# The infoWindow of each polyline in google maps is not shown using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, polyline, google-polyline

I try to display infoWindow for my polylines, In fact, I followed all steps of doing this task but still the infoWindow does not appear.. 
here I have several markers and I created path among them:

**Javascript**

```
 <style>
        #map
        {
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
  </style>
  <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBI1yC7eX6bOcbLruLZ224K5X4N-rwznjE&callback=initMap">
        </script>
        <link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script>

            var markers = [

            //1 Qazvin Takestan   
            {
            "title": 'Qazvin',
            "lat": '36.2737',
            "lng": '49.9982',
            "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b>"
            }, 

            {
            "title": 'Takestan_dest',  
            "lat": '36.0721',
            "lng": '49.7013',
            "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان</b>"
            }, 


            //1 Qazvin Takestan kooh 36.066553, 49.638426
            {
            "title": 'Qazvin',
            "lat": '36.2737',
            "lng": '49.9982',
            "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b>"
            }, 

            {
            "title": 'Takestan Kooh_dest',  
            "lat": '36.066553',
            "lng": '49.638426',
            "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان کوه</b>"
            }, 


            //2 Takestan Razan 
            {
            "title": 'Takestan_src',  
            "lat": '36.0721',
            "lng": '49.7013',
            "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان</b>"
            },

            {
            "title": 'Razan',
            "lat": '35.3914',
            "lng": '49.0337',
            "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: رزن</b>"
            },


            //3 Takestan Abhar 
            {
            "title": 'Takestan_src',  
            "lat": '36.0721',
            "lng": '49.7013',
            "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان</b>"
            },

            {
            "title": 'Abhar', 
            "lat": '36.1525',
            "lng": '49.2385',
            "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: ابهر</b>"
            },

            //4 Abhar zanjan 36.1525° N, 49.2385° E
            {
            "title": 'Takestan_src',  
            "lat": '36.1525',
            "lng": '49.2385',
            "description":"<a href='edit-stations.php?temp_id=2018080250'><b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان</b></a>"
            },

            {
            "title": 'Zanjan', 
            "lat": '36.6830',
            "lng": '48.5087',
            "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: زنجان</b>"
            },

            //5 Qazvin Ziaran 36.1185° N, 50.5265    
            {
            "title": 'Qazvin',
            "lat": '36.2737',
            "lng": '49.9982',
            "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b>"
            }, 

            {
            "title": 'Ziaran',  
            "lat": '36.1185',
            "lng": '50.5265',
            "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: زیاران</b>"
            }, 

            //6 Ziaran karaj 35.8400° N, 50.9391° E   
            {
            "title": 'Ziaran',  
            "lat": '36.1185',
            "lng": '50.5265',
            "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: زیاران</b>"
            },  

            {
            "title": 'karaj',  
            "lat": '35.8400',
            "lng": '50.9391',
            "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: کرج</b>"
            },

            //7 Qazvin Loshan 36.6294° N, 49.5140° E  
            {
            "title": 'Qazvin',
            "lat": '36.2737',
            "lng": '49.9982',
            "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b>"
            },  

            {
            "title": 'Loshan',  
            "lat": '36.6294',
            "lng": '49.5140',
            "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: لوشان</b>"
            },

            //8 Qazvin BoeenZahra 35.7677° N, 50.0573° E 
            {
            "title": 'Qazvin',
            "lat": '36.2737',
            "lng": '49.9982',
           "description": "<a href='edit-stations.php?temp_id=2018082145'><b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b></a>"
            },  

            {
            "title": 'BoeenZahra',  
            "lat": '35.7677',
            "lng": '50.0573',
            "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: بویین زهرا</b>"
            }





];
        var infowindow2;
        var poly;
        var map;
        var marker;
        var path;
        var vertices;
        var polylines = []; 
        var flightPlanCoordinates;
        var zz = 0;   
        flightPlanCoordinates =[
           [
            {lat: 36.2737, lng: 49.9982},
            {lat: 35.7677, lng: 50.0573}
            ],
            [
            {lat: 36.2737, lng: 49.9982},
            {lat:36.543726,lng: 49.574846},
            {lat: 36.6294, lng: 49.5140}
            ]
        ];

        function initMap() {           
        var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID 
        };

         // Define the symbol, using one of the predefined paths ('CIRCLE')
        // supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.
        var lineSymbol = {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          scale: 8,
          strokeColor: '#393'
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        //multi polylines
        var lat_lng = new Array();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i];
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: data.title
        });
        latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
        (function(marker, data) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        })(marker, data);
        }

        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

        //Initialize the Direction Service
        var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
         var hh =0;   
         //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
        for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {

        if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
        var src = lat_lng[i];
        var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
        i = i+1;
        service.route({
        origin: src,
        destination: des,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          //Initialize the Path Array
          path = new google.maps.MVCArray();



            //Set the Path Stroke Color
            poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
            //path: path,
            //path: flightPlanCoordinates[hh],
            icons: [{
            icon: lineSymbol,
            offset: '100%'
          }],
            map: map,
            //strokeColor: '#ec2a04'
            strokeWeight: 3.5,
            strokeColor: '#38ff45'
          });

        hh++;    

          poly.setPath(path);
          //poly.setPath(flightPlanCoordinates[0]);
          //poly.push(flightPlanCoordinates);

          polylines.push(poly);

          //polylines[0].setOptions({strokeColor: 'blue'}); 

          //var routeIndex = indexOfRequest(result);

          for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length ; i < len; i++) {
            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
          }

           animateCircle(poly);
        }
        });

        }
       //polylines[routeIndex].setPath(result.routes[0].overview_path);

        }
            createInfoWindow(poly, 'polyinfo...test'); //I tried polylines too
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        }

         function createInfoWindow(poly, content) {

    google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function(event) {
        // infowindow.content = content;
        infowindow2.setContent(content);

        // infowindow.position = event.latLng;
        infowindow2.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowindow2.open(map);
    });
}   

        // Use the DOM setInterval() function to change the offset of the symbol
        // at fixed intervals.
        function animateCircle(line) {
          var count = 0;
          window.setInterval(function() {
            count = (count + 1) % 200;
            var icons = line.get('icons');
            icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
            line.set('icons', icons);
            }, 20);
        } 

    function changeRootProperty(pathID,pathStatus)
    {
        if((pathStatus%2) == 0)
            {
                polylines[pathID].setOptions({strokeColor: 'red'});
                document.getElementById("path"+pathID).innerHTML = "<span class='label label-danger'>غیرفعال</span>";
            }
        else
            {
                polylines[pathID].setOptions({strokeColor: '#38ff45'});
                document.getElementById("path"+pathID).innerHTML = "<span class='label label-success'>فعال</span>";
            } 
    } 

  </script>
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="map" style='width:100%;height:340px;'>

</div>
```

I tried many but still I have problem, when I click on markers, it's info window appears but for polylines does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the posted code I get the javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined`, because the `DirectionsService` is asynchronous and you are calling `createInfoWindow(poly, 'polyinfo...test');` outside of its callback function (before the `poly` variable is created).

You want to call that inside the callback function:

```
function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      //Initialize the Path Array
      path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
      //Set the Path Stroke Color
      poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        icons: [{
          icon: lineSymbol,
          offset: '100%'
        }],
        map: map,
        //strokeColor: '#ec2a04'
        strokeWeight: 3.5,
        strokeColor: '#38ff45'
      });
      hh++;
      poly.setPath(path);
      polylines.push(poly);
      for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
      }
      animateCircle(poly);
      createInfoWindow(poly, 'polyinfo...test');  // <== call it inside the callback function
    }
  });
```

Once I do that, I get a new error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setContent' of undefined` because the variable `infowindow2` is never initialize, add this to your `initMap` function:

```
infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/w3e3az7n/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var markers = [

  //1 Qazvin Takestan   
  {
    "title": 'Qazvin',
    "lat": '36.2737',
    "lng": '49.9982',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b>"
  },

  {
    "title": 'Takestan_dest',
    "lat": '36.0721',
    "lng": '49.7013',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان</b>"
  },


  //1 Qazvin Takestan kooh 36.066553, 49.638426
  {
    "title": 'Qazvin',
    "lat": '36.2737',
    "lng": '49.9982',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b>"
  },

  {
    "title": 'Takestan Kooh_dest',
    "lat": '36.066553',
    "lng": '49.638426',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان کوه</b>"
  },


  //2 Takestan Razan 
  {
    "title": 'Takestan_src',
    "lat": '36.0721',
    "lng": '49.7013',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان</b>"
  },

  {
    "title": 'Razan',
    "lat": '35.3914',
    "lng": '49.0337',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: رزن</b>"
  },


  //3 Takestan Abhar 
  {
    "title": 'Takestan_src',
    "lat": '36.0721',
    "lng": '49.7013',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان</b>"
  },

  {
    "title": 'Abhar',
    "lat": '36.1525',
    "lng": '49.2385',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: ابهر</b>"
  },

  //4 Abhar zanjan 36.1525° N, 49.2385° E
  {
    "title": 'Takestan_src',
    "lat": '36.1525',
    "lng": '49.2385',
    "description": "<a href='edit-stations.php?temp_id=2018080250'><b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان</b></a>"
  },

  {
    "title": 'Zanjan',
    "lat": '36.6830',
    "lng": '48.5087',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: زنجان</b>"
  },

  //5 Qazvin Ziaran 36.1185° N, 50.5265    
  {
    "title": 'Qazvin',
    "lat": '36.2737',
    "lng": '49.9982',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b>"
  },

  {
    "title": 'Ziaran',
    "lat": '36.1185',
    "lng": '50.5265',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: زیاران</b>"
  },

  //6 Ziaran karaj 35.8400° N, 50.9391° E   
  {
    "title": 'Ziaran',
    "lat": '36.1185',
    "lng": '50.5265',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: زیاران</b>"
  },

  {
    "title": 'karaj',
    "lat": '35.8400',
    "lng": '50.9391',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: کرج</b>"
  },

  //7 Qazvin Loshan 36.6294° N, 49.5140° E  
  {
    "title": 'Qazvin',
    "lat": '36.2737',
    "lng": '49.9982',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b>"
  },

  {
    "title": 'Loshan',
    "lat": '36.6294',
    "lng": '49.5140',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: لوشان</b>"
  },

  //8 Qazvin BoeenZahra 35.7677° N, 50.0573° E 
  {
    "title": 'Qazvin',
    "lat": '36.2737',
    "lng": '49.9982',
    "description": "<a href='edit-stations.php?temp_id=2018082145'><b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b></a>"
  },

  {
    "title": 'BoeenZahra',
    "lat": '35.7677',
    "lng": '50.0573',
    "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: بویین زهرا</b>"
  }
];
var infowindow2;
var poly;
var map;
var marker;
var path;
var vertices;
var polylines = [];
var flightPlanCoordinates;
var zz = 0;
flightPlanCoordinates = [
  [{
      lat: 36.2737,
      lng: 49.9982
    },
    {
      lat: 35.7677,
      lng: 50.0573
    }
  ],
  [{
      lat: 36.2737,
      lng: 49.9982
    },
    {
      lat: 36.543726,
      lng: 49.574846
    },
    {
      lat: 36.6294,
      lng: 49.5140
    }
  ]
];

function initMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };

  // Define the symbol, using one of the predefined paths ('CIRCLE')
  // supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.
  var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 8,
    strokeColor: '#393'
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  //multi polylines
  var lat_lng = new Array();
  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i];
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: data.title
    });
    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
    (function(marker, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    })(marker, data);
  }

  map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
  map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

  //Initialize the Direction Service
  var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var hh = 0;
  //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
  for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {

    if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
      var src = lat_lng[i];
      var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
      i = i + 1;
      service.route({
        origin: src,
        destination: des,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          //Initialize the Path Array
          path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
          //Set the Path Stroke Color
          poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
            icons: [{
              icon: lineSymbol,
              offset: '100%'
            }],
            map: map,
            strokeWeight: 3.5,
            strokeColor: '#38ff45'
          });
          hh++;
          poly.setPath(path);
          polylines.push(poly);
          for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
          }

          animateCircle(poly);
          createInfoWindow(poly, 'polyinfo...test');
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

function createInfoWindow(poly, content) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function(event) {
    infowindow2.setContent(content);
    infowindow2.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow2.open(map);
  });
}

// Use the DOM setInterval() function to change the offset of the symbol
// at fixed intervals.
function animateCircle(line) {
  var count = 0;
  window.setInterval(function() {
    count = (count + 1) % 200;
    var icons = line.get('icons');
    icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
    line.set('icons', icons);
  }, 20);
}

function changeRootProperty(pathID, pathStatus) {
  if ((pathStatus % 2) == 0) {
    polylines[pathID].setOptions({
      strokeColor: 'red'
    });
    document.getElementById("path" + pathID).innerHTML = "<span class='label label-danger'>غیرفعال</span>";
  } else {
    polylines[pathID].setOptions({
      strokeColor: '#38ff45'
    });
    document.getElementById("path" + pathID).innerHTML = "<span class='label label-success'>فعال</span>";
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @geocodezip I too was getting the `Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined` error when I first tried running this and ended up getting a bit carried away. I wasn't sure if the intention was to also animate the infowindows or merely to invoke them upon clicking on each polyline so the code below is more complicated that needs be to just simply open the infowindow at a location of a polyline.

I also modified the code that generates the content for the infowindow so tht it shows the details of the current route which presumably would be intended result.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Polyline - animated infowindow &amp; poly click</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <style>
            #map{
                height:100vh;
                width:100%;
            }
            h2{
                font-size:1rem;
                margin:0 0 0.25rem 0;
                text-decoration:underline;
            }
            p,p *{
                margin:0 auto;
                font-size:0.95rem!important;
                font-family:calibri,verdana,arial!important;
                padding:0!important;
                box-sizing:border-box;
            }
            p + div{
                font-size:0.75rem;
                font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;
                color:gray;
            }
        </style>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBI1yC7eX6bOcbLruLZ224K5X4N-rwznjE&callback=initMap'></script>
        <script>

            var markers = [

                //1 Qazvin Takestan   
                {
                "title": 'Qazvin',
                "lat": '36.2737',
                "lng": '49.9982',
                "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b>"
                },             
                {
                "title": 'Takestan_dest',  
                "lat": '36.0721',
                "lng": '49.7013',
                "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان</b>"
                }, 


                //1 Qazvin Takestan kooh 36.066553, 49.638426
                {
                "title": 'Qazvin',
                "lat": '36.2737',
                "lng": '49.9982',
                "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b>"
                },         
                {
                "title": 'Takestan Kooh_dest',  
                "lat": '36.066553',
                "lng": '49.638426',
                "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان کوه</b>"
                }, 


                //2 Takestan Razan 
                {
                "title": 'Takestan_src',  
                "lat": '36.0721',
                "lng": '49.7013',
                "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان</b>"
                },
                {
                "title": 'Razan',
                "lat": '35.3914',
                "lng": '49.0337',
                "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: رزن</b>"
                },


                //3 Takestan Abhar 
                {
                "title": 'Takestan_src',  
                "lat": '36.0721',
                "lng": '49.7013',
                "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان</b>"
                },
                {
                "title": 'Abhar', 
                "lat": '36.1525',
                "lng": '49.2385',
                "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: ابهر</b>"
                },

                //4 Abhar zanjan 36.1525° N, 49.2385° E
                {
                "title": 'Takestan_src',  
                "lat": '36.1525',
                "lng": '49.2385',
                "description":"<a href='edit-stations.php?temp_id=2018080250'><b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: تاکستان</b></a>"
                },  
                {
                "title": 'Zanjan', 
                "lat": '36.6830',
                "lng": '48.5087',
                "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: زنجان</b>"
                },

                //5 Qazvin Ziaran 36.1185° N, 50.5265    
                {
                "title": 'Qazvin',
                "lat": '36.2737',
                "lng": '49.9982',
                "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b>"
                },         
                {
                "title": 'Ziaran',  
                "lat": '36.1185',
                "lng": '50.5265',
                "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: زیاران</b>"
                }, 

                //6 Ziaran karaj 35.8400° N, 50.9391° E   
                {
                "title": 'Ziaran',  
                "lat": '36.1185',
                "lng": '50.5265',
                "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: زیاران</b>"
                },         
                {
                "title": 'karaj',  
                "lat": '35.8400',
                "lng": '50.9391',
                "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: کرج</b>"
                },

                //7 Qazvin Loshan 36.6294° N, 49.5140° E  
                {
                "title": 'Qazvin',
                "lat": '36.2737',
                "lng": '49.9982',
                "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b>"
                },     
                {
                "title": 'Loshan',  
                "lat": '36.6294',
                "lng": '49.5140',
                "description":"<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: لوشان</b>"
                },

                //8 Qazvin BoeenZahra 35.7677° N, 50.0573° E 
                {
                "title": 'Qazvin',
                "lat": '36.2737',
                "lng": '49.9982',
                "description": "<a href='edit-stations.php?temp_id=2018082145'><b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: قزوین</b></a>"
                },         
                {
                "title": 'BoeenZahra',  
                "lat": '35.7677',
                "lng": '50.0573',
                "description": "<b style='padding-right:20px;font-family:tahoma;'>نام ایستگاه: بویین زهرا</b>"
                }
            ];
        </script>
        <script>
            var infoWindow;
            var poly;
            var map;
            var marker;
            var path;
            var polylines=[];

            var args=getArgs();
            var animate_circles=args.hasOwnProperty('circles') && args.circles=='false' ? false : true;
            var animate_infowindows=args.hasOwnProperty('animate') && args.animate=='true' ? true : false;
            var enable_click=args.hasOwnProperty('click') && args.click=='false' ? false : true;


            function initMap() {           
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng( markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng ),
                    zoom: 10,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID 
                };
                var lineSymbol = {
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    scale: 5,
                    strokeColor: '#393'
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions );



                //multi polylines
                var lat_lng = new Array();
                var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
                    var data = markers[i];
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( data.lat, data.lng );
                        lat_lng.push( myLatlng );

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position:myLatlng,
                        map:map,
                        title:data.title
                    });

                    latlngbounds.extend( marker.position );
                }
                map.setCenter( latlngbounds.getCenter() );
                map.fitBounds( latlngbounds );

                var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();



                for( var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++ ) {
                    if ( ( i + 1 ) < lat_lng.length ) {

                        var source = lat_lng[i];
                        var destination = lat_lng[i + 1];
                        var title=markers[ i ].title +' to ' + markers[ i+1 ].title;
                        var description=markers[ i ].description;

                        /* create the infowindow and set the contents */
                        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                            infoWindow.setMap( null );
                            infoWindow.setContent( 
                                [ 
                                    '<h2>'+title+'</h2>',
                                    '<p>'+description+'</p>',
                                    '<div>',
                                    'lat:'+markers[i].lat,
                                    ', ',
                                    'lng:'+markers[i].lng,
                                    '</div>'
                                ].join( '' )
                            );

                        i++;


                        /*********************/
                        /*
                            route config
                        */
                        var options={
                            origin: source,
                            destination: destination,
                            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING                        
                        };
                        var callback=function( result, status ) {
                            if( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK ) {
                                path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

                                var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                    icons: [{
                                        icon: lineSymbol,
                                        offset: '100%'
                                    }],
                                    map: map,
                                    strokeWeight: 3.5,
                                    strokeColor: '#38ff45',
                                    iwin:this /* infowindow - referenced in click event handler and animateCircle */
                                });


                                poly.setPath( path );
                                polylines.push( poly );

                                for( var i = 0; i < result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i++ ) {
                                    path.push( result.routes[0].overview_path[i] );
                                }


                                if( enable_click ){
                                    /* To simply open the infowindow by clicking on the polyline */
                                    google.maps.event.addListener( poly, 'click', function( event ){
                                        /* choose a location - arbitrarily this is approx 1/2 way of path */
                                        var length = this.getLength();
                                        var mid = Math.round( length / 2 );
                                        var pos = this.getAt( mid );
                                        var win = poly.get('iwin');

                                        /* set the infowindow at selected location */
                                        win.setPosition( { lat:pos.lat(), lng:pos.lng() } );

                                        /* open/close infowindow */
                                        openwin.call( this, win, map );

                                        /* change polyline colour */
                                        editpoly.call( this, poly );
                                        /*
                                            bound explicitly to the currently defined path
                                            so we can access it's properties
                                        */
                                    }.bind( path ) );
                                }


                                if( animate_circles ){
                                    animateCircle( poly, path );
                                }
                            }//end if
                        };//end callback

                        /* invoke the route request */
                        service.route( options, callback.bind( infoWindow ) );

                        /*********************/


                    }//close if

                }//close for loop
            }//end initMap



            function editpoly( poly ){
                poly.strokeColor = poly.strokeColor=='#38ff45' ? '#ff0000' : '#38ff45';
            }
            function openwin( win,map ){
                win.getMap()!==null && win.getMap()!=='undefined' ? win.close() : win.open( map )
            }




            // Use the DOM setInterval() function to change the offset of the symbol
            // at fixed intervals.

            // Note: this really thumps the processor after time

            function animateCircle( line, obj ) {
                var count = 0;
                /* 
                    if infowindow is to be animated, 
                    get a reference to the appropriate 
                    infowindow
                */
                if( animate_infowindows ){
                    var iwin=line.get('iwin');
                        iwin.open( map );

                    var i=0;
                    var x=0;
                    var pos;
                }

                window.setInterval( function() {
                    count = ( count + 1 ) % 200;

                    if( animate_infowindows ){
                        /* 
                            calculate the approximate percentage along path
                            to then find the lat/lng from the path at that
                            position
                        */
                        i = ( ( i + 1 ) % 200 );
                        x = Math.round( i / 2 / 100 * obj.getLength() );

                        pos=obj.getAt( x );
                        this.setPosition( { lat:pos.lat(), lng:pos.lng() } );
                    }


                    var icons = line.get('icons');
                        icons[0].offset = ( count / 2 ) + '%';
                    line.set( 'icons', icons );
                }.bind( iwin ), 20 );
            }


            /* 
                get querystring from url and 
                create object with parameters 
                in name/value pairs
            */
            function getArgs() {
                var a = {};
                var p = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
                for(var i=0; i < p.length;i++) {
                    var x = p[i].indexOf('=');
                    if( x == -1 ) continue;
                    a[ p[ i ].substring( 0, x ) ] = unescape( p[ i ].substring( x + 1 ) );
                }
                return a;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

By changing the url in the address bar you can enable/disable the animation of the infowindows or enable/disable the `poly click` event

[image: Click enabled with static infowindows]
Clicking on each polyline will open it's own infowindow as each line is assigned it's own. The content is generated from original `markers` data.

[image: animated infowindows]
Gets a little manic and thumps the processor even more than simply animating the circles. Each infowindow travels along the path - I was unable to bind this exactly to the circle alas.